# Will there be new releases from JBPM after 7.73.0?

Tags: jbpm, kie, kogito

We found few issues in jbpm and we were expecting those to get fixed with newer versions of jbpm.
But since July (after IBM joined the development with Red Hat) we do not see any new releases from jbpm side.
IBM has something called Kogito which is developed on top of jbpm.

Will we have new release versions from JBPM or should we switch to Kogito or some other business automation tool?

Comment: IMHO only IBM or the jbpm team can answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KIE community stopped to release 7.x version every 3-weeks like we did until 7.73.0.Final.
We still plan to release 7.x once in a while even right now we don't have set a release date for 7.74.0.Final.

Btw IBM is not behind Kogito even they are trying to help Red Hat developers to contribute to Kogito in soon future. Up to now all KIE projects and including Kogito are driven by community and developers from Red Hat.